# how to set more than one item dynamic in navigation view android

Tags: android

I am using support library 23.1.1 and I am using navigation view with Header view. There is 2 items in my navigation view named Name and Email address. I can set first item as dynamic from java code but I can not dynamic 2nd thing that is Email address. Then how to do that thing?

Comment: Mind adding some code about what you have tried?

Comment: I have tried support library 23.1.1 but didnt work like I need